# How to get Title, cookies, and post data for all tabs in IE

Tags: .net, delphi, visual-c++

I need a way to get Following data for all Tabs of IE :

1. Titles of all Tab instances.
2. Post Data when a form is submitted.
3. All Cookies

Actually my client wants to keep tab on his employees surfing behaviors, he has this requirement. I am not sure how i can do this.I guess it will be done in VC++/Delphi,Any technology will do as long as its able to produce a single executable for this.

Any help would be appreciated.

Regards

Gaurav Verma

Comment: What if someone just uses another browser?

Comment: No reason to downvote IMHO. I don't like the idea of spying employees too, but this is a valid programming question.

Comment: up and down voting does not say 'valid' or not 'valid' ... YMMV :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Going after a specific browser has some limitations.  First, you will have to stay on top of every change that the vendor makes to the browser...since the web is so dynamic and is still evolving, expect to have your program break often with every release.  Second, its easy to bypass security by installing a different browser, and there are even some that will run [completely off of a USB stick](http://portableapps.com/apps/internet/firefox_portable) without any "footprint" on the local machine.

That said, I'm not sure going after cookies and post data is worth the effort, but the best solution would be to use a proxy service of some type (could even be on the workstation itself).  You could also use a traffic monitoring program (for instance [Wireshark](http://www.wireshark.org/)) to track specific requests based on filters, but this will not "crack open" any HTTPS/FTPS streams as they are encrypted.

A Browser Helper Object would work, but again is limited to a specific browser.

Answer (score 5):

I don't think this is a good method to observe the employee's (besides the privacy issues). I would suggest to get logging from either the proxy server or the firewall.

Comment: i have told client so, but he is adamant on doing so. He doesn't want a proxy server :(

Comment: @prince But you don't need proxy, you can monitor outgoing traffic on PC itself

Comment: If you do want to go on with this I think the best way to go would be to implement a BHO (Browser Helper Object) and log all actions from there to a central place (eg a database). This is a good place to start for BHO: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb250436%28VS.85%29.aspx.